# jQuery(window).load(function() breaks script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm implementing Isotope on a site that I'm working on but I have some issues loading the script correctly, and especially on the first visit.

It seems that I have to used the (window).load function for that but if I change that in my .js-file it breaks the sctript and functionality.

The code below works all fine except for that fact that it doesn't load on the first visit of the site. It also causes some layout issues in Firefox

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog     posts
    $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });

    //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
    var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
            return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
        $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass(
            'selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

If I replace the first line of the script with the code below it loads on the first visit but the filter functionality is broken.

```
jQuery(window).load(function()
```

It should be probably be quite easy to fix but my jQuery knowledge is quite limited. Any help is much appreciated.

PS: the site uses WordPress so jQuery is in non-conflict mode.

Comment: "It seems that I have to use the (window).load function... " *Why?* Did you read that somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I found that in another tutorial on how to implement Isotope. But that one might be wrong...

Comment: Well it shouldn't make much difference, except that your code above expects that `$` will be passed in to the initialization function. When you set the function up as a "load" event handler, that will not happen, so `$` will not be correctly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why your code needs to be in a "load" event handler, but you'll need to add this as the first line of the function:

```
 var $ = window.jQuery;
```

Without that, all the references to `$` that work because of the parameter passed in to the code when it's used as a "ready" handler will be broken when it's used as a "load" handler.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to load the script correctly on first load. After adding the load event handler all styles are loaded properly on first load/view which didn't happen before. I still have a small styling issue though which only happens in Firefox but that's probably not related to this script.